# OwnerDraw ComboBox is not "styled" anymore

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

I've created a custom combobox with DrawMode = OwnerDrawVariable. Everything is fine, except it doesn't use visual styles anymore in DropDownList mode, i.e. it looks like old combobox. How can I make it drawn using visual styles? I checked VisualStyleElement class but haven't found there anything that could help me.

Does it mean that OwnerDraw combobox can't be drawn with visual styles???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in the 7.0 version of the SDK that allows drawing that style.  The ComboBoxRenderer class doesn't pay attention to DropDownStyle at all.  I think you're stuck.

Comment: Am I right that it is Windows itself who decides how to paint combobox (themed or not) based on a flag (CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED or CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE)? If yes, then it means there is no way to make it themed?

Comment: Yes.  It no doubt suppresses the custom style for appcompat reasons.