# How to display text on a progress bar control, and keep original background

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

When overriding `OnPaint()` and `OnPaintBackground()` events as follows :

```
protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e ) {
    base.OnPaint( e );
    try {
        switch ( TextVisibility  ) {
            case ProgressBarTextVisibility.None:
                return;
            case ProgressBarTextVisibility.CustomText:
                if ( progressText=="" ) { return; }
                break;
            case ProgressBarTextVisibility.Percentage:
                progressText = Value.ToString()+"%";
                break;
        }

        SizeF charSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString( progressText, ProgressFont );
        e.Graphics.DrawString(
            progressText,
            ProgressFont,
            new SolidBrush(ProgressTextColor),
            new PointF(
                Width/2-( charSize.Width/2.0F ),
                Height/2-( charSize.Height/2.0F )
            )
        );

    } catch ( Exception ee ) {

    }
}

protected override void OnPaintBackground( PaintEventArgs pevent ) {
    base.OnPaintBackground( pevent );
}
```

The result is this (progressbar is at 50%) [ pointing out that the background is not drawn at all. ] :

[image]

I get the same result as depicted above if i create a new `Label` control and set it's background to `Color.Transparent` and set dock to `Full`.

There are plenty of examples on how to add text AND draw a custom progress bar style, however I wish to keep the original progress bar visual in-tact without re-inventing the wheel. The progress portion works fine and I am happy with the native style and do not wish to redraw my own custom adaptation of it. I only wish to overlay text on top.

I have considered a `Timer` control / etc, however I also wish to keep this using as few resources as possible.

Here are some of the resources I have already been through :

- [How do I put text on ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529928/how-do-i-put-text-on-progressbar)
- [Add The Percent Into A Progress Bar (Updated)](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/94631-add-the-percent-into-a-progress-bar-updated/)
- [How do put text on ProgressBar?](http://csharpsamplecoding.blogspot.ca/2012/12/how-do-put-text-on-progressbar.html)
- ... and many more similar to above

I am using c# and the control is a custom control that extends the .NET native ProgressBar control.

## UPDATE

I will use this section to post ongoing research as I find more relevant data that is different.

- [Using Visual Styles with Custom and Owner-Drawn Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373487(v=vs.85).aspx) - this is not in .NET
- [OwnerDraw ComboBox is not “styled” anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125090/ownerdraw-combobox-is-not-styled-anymore) - tried this, but progressbar doen't support `DrawMode`
- [Enabling Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx) - this is more for how to enable styling of controls for applications compiled that don't already do this natively (for example, Visual Basic 6, Visual C++ 6, etc)
- [VisualStyleElement.ProgressBar.Bar Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.progressbar.bar(v=vs.110).aspx) - seems to be warm. no full example on implementation so will play the guessing game to try this.
- [TabControl OwnerDraw and keep the windows theme...](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21876214/TabControl-OwnerDraw-and-keep-the-windows-theme.html) - not a whole lot of information here, but this is how I kind of guessed at the `VisualStyleElement.ProgressBar.Bar` class as possibly existing.

Comment: You are using the control style *UserPaint* so your paint is been called. That means **you** have to do all the drawing. You need to subclass the control with *SetWindowSubclass* and in *WM_PAINT* of CALLBACK function do your drawing after calling *DefSubclassProc*

Answer (score -1):

Override OnLoad and call SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, false) and SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true).  That will separate background and control detail drawing.

Comment: This still doesn't draw the original windows style. (aka, the ProgressBar value bar doesn't show);